# Получить тип класса из object через рефлексию

Tags: c#, .net, классы, рефлексия

Моя задача состоит в том что бы получать все Description у свойств классов и потом записывать их, например в коллекцию, что бы в дальнейшем работать с ними, вот так реализую.

У меня есть основной класс к которому в разной степени можно добавить еще больше полей

```
    public class StatementEmployee
    {
        [Description("ФИО")]
        public string FIO { get; set; }
        [Description("Итого, руб")]
        public double TotalCurrency { get; set; }
        [Description("ИНН")]
        public string INN { get; set; }
        public object Other { get; set; }
        [Description("Субсидия")]
        public double Subsidy { get; set; }
        [Description("Штрафы")]
        public double Fine { get; set; }
        [Description("Комментарий к расчетке")]
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

и в Other я добавлю что-то рандомное по мере надобности, например:

```
    private class SalaryEmployee
    {
        [Description("Оклад")]
        public double Salary { get; set; }
        [Description("Количество рабочих часов в месяц")]
        public double WorkingHoursMonth { get; set; }
        [Description("Количество не отработанных часов")]
        public double HoursNotWorkedMonth { get; set; }
    }
```

или например

```
public class ActivitiesEmployee
    {
        [Description("Грейд")]
        public string Grade { get; set; }
        [Description("Всего трудозатрат, ч")]
        public double TotalLaborCostsTime { get; set; }
        [Description("Трудозатраты")]
        public List<WorkExpense> WorkExpense { get; set; }
        [Description("Бонусы")]
        public List<string> Bonus { get; set; }
    }
```

Потом заполняю данные и мне необходимо получить Description через рефлексию, так:

```
private static void GetDescriptionName(List<StatementEmployee> statementEmployee)
    {
        foreach (StatementEmployee item in statementEmployee)
        {
            var t = typeof(StatementEmployee);
            foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties())
            {
                var desc = (prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true)
                    .FirstOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute).Description; // Description
                var propertyValue = prop.GetValue(item, null); // Value
            }
        }
    }
```

Но при попадании на Object я не вижу класс который в нем находится, можно ли как то реализовать данный функционал? использовать Dynamic? Или дженерик?

**UPD**

```
    public class WorkExpense
    {
        [Description("Вид деятельности")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Description("Часы")]
        public double Hours { get; set; }
        [Description("Сумма")]
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        [Description("ДДС")]
        public string DDS { get; set; }
    }
```

Дополнительная вводная: в общем классе, может быть список из WorkExpense.
Я добавляю проверку на то что является ли то что пришло ко мне коллекцией

```
    public static bool IsList(object o)
    {
        if (o == null) return false;
        return o is IList &&
               o.GetType().IsGenericType &&
               o.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(List<>));
    }
```

И если что выбираю первый элемент что бы просто пройтись по всем Description и получить их

```
        if (IsList(statementEmployee))
        {
            statementEmployee = statementEmployee[0];
        }
```

Comment: *Но при попадании на Object я не вижу класс который в нем находится* вы имеет ввиду, что вы привели объект вашего класса к типу `object`, и теперь не знаете, как получить его свойства? Зачем вам класть ваши `Emloyee` в object?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko что бы создавать иллюзию динамического класса. В будущем я заполняю данные поля и потом по Description формирую столбцы в Excel в которые и выведу эти данные. Просто или делать так как я пытаюсь или создавать около 20 разных классов с одинаковыми свойствами и парами разных

Comment: Теперь понял задание. Дело в том, что в C# не динамически типизированный язык программирования. Мы не можем, как в JS, работать с объектами как с массивом свойств разных типов. Я предлагаю вам просто перечислить эти свойства при записи файла, а не проходиться по ним в цикле. Можно еще попробовать использование сериализации, но как потом xml правильно в xlsx запихнуть - пока я такого не пробовал.

Comment: Вы не пробовали просто рекурсивно вызвать процедуру для `Other`?

Comment: @Kamushek у other я не знаю тип, его я могу получить если при нахождении оного я введу получение его типа из коллекции statementEmployee.FirstOrDefault().Other.GetType(); и уже по типу бежать, да, вот так можно

Comment: Вы можете взять его тип через `GetType`, а дальше будет тот же самый код по факту

Comment: @Kamushek сам класс будет хранить только object, а вот коллекцию уже хранит тип, да, вот так я могу сделать

Comment: @Andrei Khotko Что значит перечислить свойства при записи файла? Мне просто по решению надо что бы свойства были так подписаны, так как они могут изменяться, и не было завязки на имени

Comment: можно использовать контсрукции типа is и as, но вам понадобится сканер, который как раз и будет производить конвертацию вашего объекта в нужный класс, по хорошему, такие классы можно вообще наследовать от абстрактного, и объединять в список по абстрактному классу.

Comment: @Unnamed просто берете и в тупую делаете в пределах метода записи что-то вроде `binaryWriter.Write(empl.FIO); binaryWriter.Write(empl.TotalCurrency);` и т.д.

Comment: @Andrei Khotko, слишком привязывает к коду, хотелось что бы именно не было такой завязки, при изменении какого либо свойства(добавления, удаления) приходилось бы только убирать его заполнение, а отображение не было бы задействовано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал пример, который выводит описание и значение свойства, рекурсивно углубляясь в случае, когда у свойства нет атрибута `Description`. По нему должно быть всё очевидно. А вы уверены, что рефлексия это именно то, что вам нужно? Может быть можно обойтись чем-то вроде словарей?

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var statement = new StatementEmployee {Other = new SalaryEmployee()};
        foreach (var item in GetDescriptionNameDictionary(statement))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Desc: {item.Key}, Value: {item.Value}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IDictionary<string, object> GetDescriptionNameDictionary(object statementEmployee)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        var t = statementEmployee.GetType();
        foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties())
        {
            var a = GetPropertyDescriptionValue(statementEmployee, prop);
            if (a.description != null)
            {
                dict.Add(a.description, a.value);
            }
            else
            {
                var inner = GetDescriptionNameDictionary(a.value);
                foreach (var o in inner)
                    dict.Add(o.Key, o.Value);
            }
        }

        return dict;
    }

    private static (string description, object value) GetPropertyDescriptionValue(object obj, PropertyInfo prop)
    {
        var t = obj.GetType();
        var desc = (prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true)
            .FirstOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute)?.Description; // Description
        var propertyValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null); // Value
        return (desc, propertyValue);
    }
```

Comment: при заполнении словаря со значением, например "Фио", "что то там", мне надо завязываться на том что я буду всегда искать ФИО, и если его не найду то ошибка (это если его изменят). И объясните пожалуйста что это за конструкция private static (string description, object value) GetPropertyDescriptionValue(object obj, PropertyInfo prop) она не отрабатывает у меня

Comment: Это [кортежи из С#7](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples). Того же эффекта можно добиться, создав простую структуру и заменив `(string description, object value) ` на неё. Сама структурка: `struct DescriptionValue
        {
            public string Description { get; }
            public object Value { get; }

            public DescriptionValue(string description, object value)
            {
                Description = description;
                Value = value;
            }
        }`

Comment: к сожалению работаю с C#4 там нет кортежей, спасибо за разъяснение, сейчас проверю как это будет для моего решения

Comment: спасибо, для первого класса отлично отрабатывает! Но возникает такая проблема в том, что я не могу работать тогда с классами в которых имеется коллекция. Это например ActivitiesEmployee, возникает ошибка из за получения коллекции и ее обработки. Можно ли избежать данную проблему если не указывать явно класс?

Comment: @Unnamed, можете добавить ещё класс `WorkExpense` и поподробнее описать ошибку?

Comment: Добавил в UPD класс. Скорее всего даже нет проблемы собственно, я решил через получение единственного экземпляра из коллекции. Просто потом мне необходимо проверять чтоб данные которые будут в таких коллекциях не исключались так как у них есть Description а бралось их Name и создавалась как Key а всё что внутри было как Value

Comment: Валидно :) Только я бы расширил тип с `List<>` хотя бы до `IList<>`, но лучше конечно взять наиболее общий тип, допускаемый ТЗ, например, `IEnumerable<>`.